# Switching INSERT to REPLACE makes DATE_SUB() result invalid

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following query working fine ignoring on unique key:

```
insert_post = ("""INSERT IGNORE INTO posts 
                SET internal = %s,
                    schedule_date = DATE_SUB(%s, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
               """)
```

As soon as I switch the query to `REPLACE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2017-08-19T12:45:00-0500'
```

I under stand that the incoming value format is not compatible with MySQL datetime column, but it doesn't seem to be an issue on my initial `INSERT`.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Here's an SQL fiddle, but the panel won't run the DDL/DML so don't expect much more than a schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/656a3/2

Edit: Here's the working SQLfiddle showing the replicated error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c13f45/1

Comment: have you tried to run your query as a select statement before an insert? i do this when i debug and sometimes its super helpful in identifying why something fails.

Comment: @ttallierchio SELECT with the DATE_SUB formatting works fine.

Comment: Write your DML on the left side: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c13f45/1 or use rexester: http://rextester.com/TENRB4721

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks. I added the working fiddle with the `REPLACE` triggering the error.

Comment: What are your `REPLACE` and `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I'm not sure what you mean, the entire query I'm trying run is: `REPLACE INTO posts 
                SET internal = 1,
                    schedule_date = DATE_SUB('2017-06-27T08:30:00-0500', INTERVAL 2 HOUR)`

Answer (score 0):

so after some playing around it appears replace and insert ignore act differently. the insert will truncate the data but still insert. the replace will just downright fail.

you will have to use the proper date time format for this @eht.

to give a little more information the insert ignore throws a warning about the data being truncated. the replace throws an error and stops execution.

Comment: "If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. [...] With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead" [INSERT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: Interesting that `REPLACE IGNORE` can not be invoked for the same result.

Comment: Paul is correct it just tells you there is a problem. but after checking the documentation there does not appear a replace ignore. also just tried on the latest version of my sql.

Answer (score 0):

'INSERT IGNORE' was able to ignore the warning thrown and complete the insert with the properly formatted `datetime`.

`REPLACE` was not able to ignore malformed timestamp and would cause the error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2017-08-19T12:45:00-0500'
```

The solution involved <strike>wrapping the incoming timestamp with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`</strike> parsing and reorganizing the timestamp like this:

```
schedule_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(item['scheduleDate'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S-%f") # 2017-06-27T08:30:00-0500 -> # 2017-06-27T08:30:00.050000
formatted_schedule_date = schedule_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The working `REPLACE` query is shown here:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO posts 
                SET internal = 1,
                    schedule_date = DATE_SUB(%s, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Updated my answer with query executing and expected data inserted.